# Restar días a una fecha en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

En una tabla de mi base de datos tengo **campo1** que contiene registros de fechas y en la misma tengo a **campo2** que contiene registros de dias.
Quiero obtener la fecha que me arrojaría si a **campo1** le resto los días que **campo2** y lo estoy intentando de esta manera

```
SELECT (campo1, INTERVAL -campo2 DAY) as fecha FROM nombretabla
```

Pero consigo un error de sintaxis. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con la siguiente consulta debería funcionar:

```
select campo1 - interval campo2 day as fecha
  from nombretabla
```